# Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}x^3 + 2x + 1 = 4$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits, solution-verification

Prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}x^3 + 2x + 1 = 4$.

*Proof*: Suppose $\epsilon > 0$. Note we have
$$
|x^3 + 2x + 1 - 4| = |x^3 + 2x -3| = |x-1||x^2 + x + 3|.
$$
Let $|x-1| \leq 1 \implies 0 \leq x \leq 2 $. Observe again that
$$
|x-1||x^2 + x + 3| \leq |x-1|\left(|x|^2 + |x| + 3\right) \leq 9\cdot |x-1|. 
$$
Choose $\delta = \min\{\frac\epsilon 9, 1\}$. Finally,
$$9\cdot |x-1| < \epsilon.$$

Does this proof work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your proof seems fine, for more clarity we could write that for any $\varepsilon$ we have

$$
|x^3 + 2x + 1 - 4| = |x-1||x^2 + x + 3| \leq |x-1|\left(|x|^2 + |x| + 3\right) \leq 9\cdot |x-1| < \varepsilon
$$

for $\delta = \min\{\frac\epsilon 9, 1\}$, which proves the statement.